# Sonata admin input value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, sonata-admin

How i can get admin sonata form input value in javascript? Entity name is Url, and field name is url.

In my twig base_edit_form_extend.html.twig inside form tag:

```
onsubmit="return validate(this);"
```

and here is script:

```
 <script>
        function validate(form) {

            ...

            return alert({{ object.getUrl }});
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Get the input value inside these js function?

Comment: Or get the form action attribute?

Comment: How i can get input value in js function inside twig?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what is a form input value, as far as I know a form can contain inputs and them can have values. May be you means form action value?